# Grails Reverse Engineer Database

Tags: grails, grails-orm, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to evaluate Grails as a solution for an upcoming project. There is already a large database in use that won't be modified much if it all. I wan't to reverse engineer the database into GORM domain objects as a starting point.

I found one here http://www.grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer. I got it installed and configured however when I run it I see the same error over and over. The stacktrace is below.

Can someone help me correct the error, or recommend another tool for reverse engineering to grails? I've used Netbeans in the past to reverse engineer databases to JPA entities that worked out pretty well. I'm hoping for something similar with Grails.

```
| Error Error executing script DbReverseEngineer: javax/transaction/Transaction (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Us
e --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/Transaction
        at grails.plugin.reveng.GrailsJdbcBinder.readDatabaseSchema(GrailsJdbcBinder.groovy:51)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.readFromDatabase(JDBCBinder.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder$readFromDatabase.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.GrailsJdbcMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(GrailsJdbcMetaDataConfiguration.groovy:32)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.GrailsJdbcMetaDataConfiguration$readFromJDBC.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.Reenigne.buildConfiguration(Reenigne.groovy:114)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.Reenigne.execute(Reenigne.groovy:60)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.Reenigne$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.RevengRunner.run(RevengRunner.groovy:81)
        at grails.plugin.reveng.RevengRunner$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at DbReverseEngineer$_run_closure1.doCall(DbReverseEngineer:36)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:1
85)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.Transaction
        ... 29 more
| Error Error executing script DbReverseEngineer: javax/transaction/Transaction
```

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually this plugin is not compatible with Hibernate 4... yet. But since the last push was like ages ago, it doesn't look like that you will get a new version soon enough to work with it :)

However, you can still keep using this version of Grails and the db-reverse-engineer:0.5 plugin, by switching your Hibernate version, back to 3. And it is quite easy to do so !

In BuildConfig.groovy, comment the line 
runtime ":hibernate4:4.X.X.X"

And add instead:
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"

(And btw, do not forget to add the correct connector to your database, I use myself this dependency: 
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22' 
)

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4, I'll try switching it Hibernate 3 and see what happens. Once it is reverse engineered, can I switch it back to Hibernate 4 without issue?

Comment: It should be alright... The problem comes from the Hibernate API, which changed from H3 to H4. That's why The reverse engineering plugin doesn't work anymore.

However, you might have to adjust it a bit. And never forget that this reveng. plugin was never finished. It is really useful, but should serve as a basis which you need to adapt. I'm working on it though, at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the plugin uses [Hibernate Tools](http://hibernate.org/tools/) to do the reverse-engineering, so you could try just using those directly.

Comment: Once in the Hibernate Code Generation Configuration window, do I simply choose Domain as the type of Exporter? Then, copy and paste into grails-app/domain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I have no idea.

Comment: so far, I created the domain classes and the hibernate xml files. The domain classes were renamed to *.groovy and put in /src/main/groovy/com/app, the hibernate xml files were put into /conf. So far, I'm able to generate individual CRUD interfaces. I wish the wildcard would work in this regards.

Comment: To further my past comment, you can keep .java classes with EJB annotation, no need to rename them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version which fixs many bugs such this :It is `0.5.1` insead of `0.5`

## BuildConfig.groovy

```
runtime ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5.1'
```

Comment: I received the same error using version 0.5.1. Switching to Hibernate 3 as suggested by @Loic Cara worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem but I didn't switch to hibernate 3.x version the main problem is connector, un comment the mysql connector in BuildConfig.groovy
and I have added the javax.transaction jar in lib folder of grails application this solved the problem